# Static version of R Shiny app using shinylive package failing to preload packages using webR

Tags: r, shiny, github-pages, r-shinylive

I'm trying to create a static version of my app and set it up as the Github Pages website. Here's a link to my folder containing the static version of the app created by the shinylive package https://github.com/StatsDasha/MO-E-EQI/tree/main/docs and this is the Github Pages website created https://statsdasha.github.io/MO-E-EQI/. You can see that the app is partially loading, but seems to be failing to execute a lot of the functionality of the app from (what I suspect) failing to load all the packages.

It fails with the following js console output (truncated):

```
load-shinylive-sw.js:37 Service Worker registered
shinylive.js:21554 Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: https://reactjs.org/link/react-devtools
shinylive.js:31930 WebR is using `PostMessage` communication channel, nested R REPLs are not available.
Xs @ shinylive.js:31930
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21) -- "Already Tomorrow"
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:Copyright (C) 2023 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:Platform: wasm32-unknown-emscripten (32-bit)
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:Type 'contributors()' for more information and
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:Type 'q()' to quit R.
shinylive.js:34937 preload echo:
shinylive.js:34938 preload error:Downloading webR package: Rcpp
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938 preload error:Downloading webR package: R6
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938 preload error:Downloading webR package: fastmap
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938 preload error:Downloading webR package: rlang
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938 preload error:Downloading webR package: later
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938 preload error:Downloading webR package: magrittr
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938 preload error:Downloading webR package: promises
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938 preload error:Downloading webR package: httpuv
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938 preload error:Downloading webR package: mime
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938 preload error:Downloading webR package: jsonlite
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938 preload error:Downloading webR package: xtable
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938 preload error:Downloading webR package: base64enc
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938 preload error:Downloading webR package: digest
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938 preload error:Downloading webR package: ellipsis
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938 preload error:Downloading webR package: htmltools
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938 preload error:Downloading webR package: fontawesome
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938 preload error:Downloading webR package: sourcetools
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938 preload error:Downloading webR package: crayon
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938 preload error:Downloading webR package: withr
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938 preload error:Downloading webR package: commonmark
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938 preload error:Downloading webR package: glue
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938 preload error:Downloading webR package: cachem
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938 preload error:Downloading webR package: jquerylib
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938 preload error:Downloading webR package: cli
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938 preload error:Downloading webR package: lifecycle
_error @ shinylive.js:34938
shinylive.js:34938 preload error:Downloading webR package: memoise
.......
```

I can't really figure out why it seems that webR is failing to load any packages and it seems to have the only problem.

Comment: These preload errors are "normal", they always occur. I think all packages are finally loaded in spite of this issue, otherwise the app would not work.

Answer (score 0):

The `"preload error: Downloading webR package: {package}"` message will appear during the loading process of an r-shinylive app. It's important to note that this error does not indicate any serious issue.

During the app's loading phase, various R packages compiled for webR are downloaded into the browser session to facilitate the functioning of the shinylive app. However, the underlying webR session is configured to use the JavaScript function `console.error()` for both `message()` and `warning()` function calls. This setup is because these functions write messages to `STDERR` rather than `STDOUT`.

Ideally, messages generated by `message()` should be directed to `console.log()` and those from `warning()` to `console.warn()`. Only errors originating from `stop()` should be directed to `console.error()`. Hopefully that will be addressed in the future.